# boost::enable_if_c error: is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost, sfinae, enable-if

I want to disallow instantiating a class template (`PointCloud`) for types with particular type traits. In the following example, I want to only allow types with `is_good` defined to be used:

```
#include <boost/core/enable_if.hpp>

class PointType1 {};

class PointType2 {};


template <typename T>
struct is_good
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_good<PointType1>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename TPoint, typename boost::enable_if_c<is_good<TPoint>::value>::type = 0>
class PointCloud
{
};


int main()
{
  PointCloud<PointType1> pointCloud1;

  //PointCloud<PointType2> pointCloud2;

  return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: 'boost::enable_if_c<true, void>::type {aka void}' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
   PointCloud<PointType1> pointCloud1;
                        ^
```

From my understanding, `enable_if_c` is supposed to define `::type` to be `TPoint` if `is_good<TPoint>::value` is `true`. If it is `false`, then `::type` is not defined, so the SFINAE should kick in. I also thought the `typename` would be indicating that this is indeed a type parameter.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate `PointCloud<PointType1>`, `is_good<TPoint>::value` is `true` and `boost::enable_if_c<is_good<TPoint>::value>::type` is `void`.

As the error message says, `void` is not a valid type for a [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).

To fix the error, specify the second type argument for [`enable_if_c`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/core/doc/html/core/enable_if.html) instead of using the default argument `void`

```
template <typename TPoint,
          typename boost::enable_if_c<is_good<TPoint>::value, int>::type = 0>
                                                            ^^^^^
```

Comment: But this IS a type template parameter, no? Like isn't `2` a non-type template parameter, but `typedef anything` is a type template parameter? I guess I also don't understand the =0 at the end here - in a function template this just makes the argument a dummy argument when you pass nothing to it and the function doesn't get added to the overload set, but for a class template what does it mean to default the template argument to 0?

Comment: @David No, that's a non type parameter. The `typename` there is because the `::type` is dependent on `TPoint` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/241631)), so you need to tell the compiler it's a dependent name. `= 0` is a default template argument, just like with a default argument for a function parameter, it means you don't necessarily have to specify the template argument when instantiating the class.

Comment: So why is it a non type parameter? It evaluates to 'int' in your example case, which is a type, right?

Comment: @DavidDoria Yes, but it's not an unbounded set of possible types, like `template<class T>` is. If you write `template<int N>`, then `N` is a non-type template parameter. Not sure how it gets that name, but maybe it's because the other kind are *type template parameters*